# Send media to whatsapp via conversation api

Tags: node.js, twilio, whatsapp

So I found in twilio docs how to send media via api, but I need to map to conversation id as well. I see there is possibility to pass mediaSid, but I haven't found how to get that id and upload media. Any guess?

So it is possible to send

```
client.messages
      .create({
        from: "whatsapp:your_number",
        to: "whatsapp:recepient_number",,
        mediaUrl: [mediaUrl],
      })
```

But I used conversation api to send sms and WhatsApp messages

```
client.conversations.v1
      .conversations(conversationId)
      .messages.create({
        author,
        body,
        attributes,
      })
```

So if conversation has linked participants with prefix *whatsapp:*, it will send message to WhatsApp. It is possible to add messageSid to create method, but I don't know how to upload media to twilio to get that sid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conversations does it slightly differently, I believe you're talking about a backend use case (without using an SDK).

You use the [Media](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/media-resource) resource to upload media, and get mediaSids, then you attach the mediaSids to the message when posting through the [Message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/conversation-message-resource) resource.

As you may note, Media resource is not represented in the helper libraries (yet), so you will need to craft requests to it manually, using [fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-fetch) or something similar. You can post to the Messages resource with a helper library, just as you have shown in the question.

Then send the message normally (using a helper library) to a conversation containing a whatsapp participant, **attach a mediaSid to it**. Note that certain [media size limits](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/conversations-limits#media-limits) apply.

Comment: any guesses why I can't send media and body? I am currently using   
```const message = await client.conversations.v1
        .conversations(conversationId)
        .messages.create({
          author,
          body,
          mediaSid,
        });```
and it sends media without text

Comment: Twilio support answered that there is no possibility to send media and text message at once with conversation API, you should send those messages separately